# Why does MongoDB's "$and" operator sometimes use a different plan vs. specifying the criteria inline?

Tags: mongodb

It seems to me that the following two queries should have exactly the same "explain" output:

**Query 1:**

```
{
    $and: [
        { $or: [
            { Foo: "123" },
            { Bar: "456" }
        ] },
        { Baz: { $in: ["abc", "def"] } }
    ]
}
```

**Query 2:**

```
{
    $or: [
        { Foo: "123" },
        { Bar: "456" }
    ],
    Baz: { $in: ["abc", "def"] } }
}
```

Note that I have indexes on `{ Foo: -1, Baz: -1 }` and `{ Bar: -1, Baz: -1 }`, so this is optimized for the `$or` operator. And in fact, in the version for Query 2, in the explain output, I see two `clauses`, both with appropriate index bounds, one for `(Foo, Baz)` and one for `(Bar, Baz)`. MongoDB is doing exactly what it's supposed to.

But in the first version (Query 1), there are no `clauses` anymore. It gives me a `BasicCursor` with no index bounds specified.

What's the difference between these two queries? Why does Mongo seem to be able to optimize #2 but not #1?

Right now I'm testing these queries using MongoVue, so I have control over the JSON, but ultimately I'm going to be using the C# driver, and I'm pretty sure it will always emit the syntax in #1 and not #2, so it's important to find out what's going on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug of some kind in mongodb. What version are you using?

According to [that bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11517) the issue is resolved in `2.5.3`.

Until we move to the later versions (I am at `2.4.6`) we will have to be careful with the `$and` operator.

I am going to try it in `2.6` as well.

UPDATE:

Indeed it is fixed in 2.6.3 that I am now.

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "Fields" : { "K1" : 123, "K2" : 456 } }
{ "_id" : 2, "Fields" : { "K1" : 456, "K2" : 123 } }
> db.test.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.test"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "Fields.K1" : 1
        },
        "name" : "Fields.K1_1",
        "ns" : "test.test"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "Fields.K2" : 1
        },
        "name" : "Fields.K2_1",
        "ns" : "test.test"
    }
]

> db.test.find({"$and" : [{ "Fields.K1" : 123, "Fields.K2" : 456}]}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Fields.K1_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 4,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "Fields.K1" : [
            [
                123,
                123
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "benihime:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
> db.test.find({ "Fields.K1" : 123, "Fields.K2" : 456}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor Fields.K1_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 4,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "Fields.K1" : [
            [
                123,
                123
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "benihime:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: That could explain it; we're on a much older version (2.0 I think).